# WhatsAPP - MS Teams integration via Twilio

Tags: twilio, webhooks, microsoft-teams, whatsapp

I would like to integrate WhatsApp business to MS Teams. When I send a message via WhatsApp it is received in Twilio. I set webhook in Teams and in Twilio also, but Twilio can't forward the message to the Teams.

The Twilio give me a

> 11200 ERROR There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL.

I checked the response of Teams and I found this in the body:

> "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook."

I tested the webhook via curl and I received the text in channel of Teams.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the [MS Teams documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors) (emphasis mine):

> If Incoming Webhooks are enabled for a team in any channel, it exposes the HTTPS endpoint, which accepts ***correctly formatted JSON*** and inserts the messages into that channel.

[Twilio webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request) are sent in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you will need something in the middle to reformat the Twilio webhook into a format that MS Teams can ingest.

From a quick search, it's a bit difficult to find a reference for what JSON that MS Teams actually expects. [This page has some examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using).

To do the reformatting, you could use a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions). Code like this might well work for a basic text message into Teams:

```js
const got = require("got");

exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const teamsWebhookUrl = context.TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL;
  const teamsPayload = {
    text: event.Body
  };

  try {
    await got(teamsWebhookUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(teamsPayload),
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    );
    const response = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    callback(null, response);
  } catch(error) {
    callback(error);
  }
}
```

This is untested, but the idea is that it builds a simple text message [using the JSON from this curl example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-messages-using-curl-and-powershell) and send it to the Teams webhook URL using [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got). If there is a successful response from Teams then an empty response is sent back to the original Twilio webhook. If there is an error, then that error is logged in the Twilio debugger.

To use this code you will need to install got in the dependencies and add the Teams webhook URL in the environment variables.

Comment: @henrik, This answer seems accurate to me, there should be some problem with the payload been sent to Teams from Twilio. Please have a look at the examples shared in the answer.